# To which should add shipping_charges?

Tags: mysql, laravel

> I'm sorry it seems be weird! but I'm so confused! bear with me:)

I'm new with E-commerce I just create simple app via Laravel, I design this database for it:

[image]

I got in my mind tow questions:

- I'm confused with where should I add `shipping_charges` column for order in which table?!
- I have governorates(cities) so `shipping_charges` in the capital of my country should be 5$ and others cities should be 10$. How can handle the price of the cities?

Comment: Not easy to answer, once you get to a comprehensive sales system shipping rates can depend on so many things like specific customers or volume of purchase etc etc etc

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry  not mention this: there is no payment in my app just pay on delivery!

Comment: When you pay is irrelevent to my comment

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yeah I know that + my app is simple one there is all of these things that you mention it . just order products with them price of course then the price of shipping_charge depend on the city then total of the price, then and company take the order to the customer again depend on phone number, and that's it

Comment: there is no****

Comment: if the user changes the address, it will also change any previous orders with that same address_id, no?  unless you don't care about keeping accurate historical records, i would add columns to the orders table for whatever shouldn't change after the fact (e.g. shipping address, shipping charges, basically anything associated with an order)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to put `shipping_charges` in `governorates` table because it belongs to it. You can make separate table `governorate_to_shipping` but it's not neccessary.

In order you have `address_id` in addresses you have `governorate_id` so you can join this tables to `governorates` table and get `shipping_charge` from it.

Comment: that's mean I have to put shipping_charges in governorates not in addresses table ?

Comment: Yes, every order may have different adresses, if you put charge in adresses table and it changes old adresses will have old shipping charges. If this is what you need then put it in adresses table and assign values by checking if governorate is capital

Comment: Sorry  not mention this: there is no payment in my app just pay on delivery!

Comment: That's irrelevant in this case. If shipping rate does not depends on other things you can place it both `governorates` table and `adresses` table

Comment: yeah, it was for more  info + the process just order products with them price of course then the price of shipping_charge depend on the city then total of the price, then and company takes the order to the customer depend on phone number, and that's it